# Regex everything after, but not including

Tags: regex

I am trying to regex the following string:

```
https://www.amazon.com/Tapps-Top-Apps-and-Games/dp/B00VU2BZRO/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&amp;qid=1527813329&amp;sr=8-3&amp;keywords=poop
```

I want only `B00VU2BZRO`.

This substring is always going to be a 10 characters, alphanumeric, preceded by `dp/`.

So far I have the following regex:

```
[d][p][\/][0-9B][0-9A-Z]{9}
```

This matches `dp/B00VU2BZRO`

I want to match only `B00VU2BZRO` with no `dp/`

How do I regex this?

Comment: Add a language tag and show how you apply it. Capture groups and positive look behind may both work.

Comment: Just for improving searchability, to others, this is how you extract the **ASIN** from an Amazon URL.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one regex option which would produce an exact match of what you want:

```
(?<=dp\/)(.*)(?=\/)
```

### Demo

Note that this solution makes no assumptions about the length of the path fragment occurring after `dp/`.  If you want to match a certain number of characters, replace `(.*)` with `(.{10})`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your language/method of application, you have a couple of options.

1. **Positive look behind**. This will make your regex more complicated, but will make it match what you want exactly:

   ```
   (<=dp/)[0-9A-Z]{10}
   ```

   The construct `(<=...)` is called a positive look behind. It will not consume any of the string, but will only allow the match to happen if the pattern between the parens is matched.
2. **Capture group**. This will make the regex itself slightly simpler, but will add a step to the extraction process:

   ```
   dp/([0-9A-Z]{10})
   ```

   Anything between plain parens is a capture group. The entire pattern will be matched, including `dp/`, but most languages will give you a way of extracting the portion you are interested in.

Depending on your language, you may need to escape the forward slash (`/`).

As an aside, you never need to create a character class for single characters: `[d][p][\/]` can equally well be written as just `dp\/`.